# Calculating the BigO for a code

Tags: java, algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I read an article online. The BigO for the below code as per my understanding should be O(n). As the loop runs n times. But the correct answer in the articles shows as O(1). With the explanation

> The code declares exactly 4 variables: `i`, `j`, `k` and `t`. 4 = constant = O(1).

How?

As per my understanding, the loop runs n times hence O(n)

```
int fibonacci(int n)
{
   int i = 0, j = 1, k, t;
   for (k = 1; k <= n; ++k)
   {
     t = i + j;
     i = j;
     j = t;
   }
   return j;
}
```

Screenshot attached
[image]

Comment: There's...no feasible way that this code runs in constant time.

Comment: The variable declaration time complexity is constant. However, the subsequent loop in the code definitely isn't. Maybe the article is missing a bit? **Edit** after screenshot: looks like a test rather than an article, and looks **wrong**.

Comment: Please link to one of the articles

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've mistaken memory complexity for time complexity. The time complexity of the algorithm is `O(n)`. However, the memory, *sometimes called space*, complexity of the algorithm is `O(1)`, as 4 variables are allocated.

Answer (score 1):

Formally, big-O notation describes the degree of complexity.

To calculate big-O notation:

identify formula for algorithm complexity. Let's say, for example, two loops with another one nested inside, then another three loops not nested: 2N² + 3N
remove everything except the highest term: 2N²
remove all constants: N²
In other words two loops with another one nested inside, then another three loops not nested is O(N²)

This of course assumes that what you have in your loops are simple instructions. If you have for example sort() inside the loop, you'll have to multiply complexity of the loop by the complexity of the sort() implementation your underlying language/library is using

**By the mathematical logic of it, the Big O notation for your program is O(N), and not O(1).
In which case, either the article is wrong, or your understanding of what it is saying is incorrect and incomplete, with only the partial text being put over here.**

Comment: You missed the fact that the question is asking for *memory complexity*.

Comment: However, your screenshot added later shows memory complexity. Because you assign memory values to a constant number of variables, memory complexity is O(1). 
Your question was asking about time complexity earlier. I hope this comment, alongwith the earlier answer, helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you pass 'n' a constant value it's Time Complexity O(1)

```
// Here c is a constant   


for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) {  
        // some O(1) expressions
   }
```

A loop or recursion that runs a constant number of times is also considered as O(1).

If you pass 'n' a variable it's Time Complexity O(n).

```
 // Here c is a positive integer constant   


for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += c) {  
        // some O(1) expressions
   }
```

Time Complexity of a loop is considered as O(n) if the loop variables is incremented / decremented by a constant amount.

Source: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-4-analysis-of-loops/

Comment: The loop is bound by `n`.